# v-for with v-if on the same node

Tags: vue.js

i have a table that displays customers details with thier invoices, inside the table i want to check for each customer, if he has made full payment, part payment or none. but the table displays **"SUCCESS DANGER"** if the the customer has made full payment, **WARNING DANGER** if part payment of invoice. The outcome i want is below the code

This is the code for the table

```
     <tbody v-for="(invoice,index) in customer.invoices" :key="invoice.id">
        <td v-for="(payment,i) in customer.payments" v-if="payment.invoice_id === invoice.id">
            <span v-if="customer.payments[i].amount_paid === invoice.total">success</span>
            <span v-else-if="customer.payments[i].amount_paid > 0 && customer.payments[i].amount_paid < invoice.total">warning</span>
            <span else>danger</span>
       </td>
  </tbody>
```

This is the outcome that i get the **status of payment**

```
  fullpayment => success not "success warning"
  partpayment => warning not "warning danger"
  none    => DANGER
```

this is the data that i used
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36zZb.png)

[image]

Comment: Data given to this would be necessary. This is also quite inefficient probably and I assume there’s multiple payments per invoice which will make this output multiple values. Also why use `customer.payments[i]` when you already have `payment`?

Comment: @samikuhmonen i have added the data and the table. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Not `else`, it should be `v-else`

Comment: I would rework this so that you get the v-if and v-for on different lines. If you need to filter the list then use computed property. If you need to conditionally render the v-for then you can put the v-if on a v-container tag around the v-for.